# Show that $A^2+B^2+C^2=D^2$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, volume

In an orthogonal parallellepipide (cuboid) with sides $a,b,c$, a plane bisects it in halv through three side-diagonals of the cuboid, leaving a tetrahedral with three of it's sides being right triangles. Denote these right triangle sides by $A,B,C$ and denote the fourth side by $D$. Show that $A^2+B^2+C^2=D^2.$

My method starts with putting the cuboid in a coordinate system like this below.

Fixing the vectors $\vec{u}=(a,0,0)-(0,0,-c) = (a,0,c)$ and $\vec{v}=(a,b,-c)-(0,0,-c)=(a,b,0).$

Now, the area of the fourth triangle is $$D=\frac{1}{2}|\vec{u}\times\vec{v}|= \frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{vmatrix}
0 & c \\ 
b & 0
\end{vmatrix}-\begin{vmatrix}
a & c \\ 
a & 0
\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}
a & 0 \\ 
a & b
\end{vmatrix}\right)=-\frac{bc}{2}+\frac{ac}{2}+\frac{ab}{2}.$$

Now, by the figure it follows that $A^2=\frac{b^2c^2}{4}, \ B^2=\frac{a^2b^2}{4}$ and $C^2=\frac{a^2c^2}{4}$ so $$A^2+B^2+C^2=\frac{b^2c^2}{4}+\frac{a^2b^2}{4}+\frac{a^2c^2}{4}.$$

But Squaring $D$ does not give me $\frac{b^2c^2}{4}+\frac{a^2b^2}{4}+\frac{a^2c^2}{4}.$ This method should work!

**

### Note: I don't want to know other methods, I want to know why the above doesn't work.

**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The result you want to prove has a name : it is called [De Gua's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrirectangularTetrahedron.html).

In fact :

$$\vec{u}\times\vec{v}=\begin{pmatrix}
-bc\\ \ \ ac\\ \ \ ab 
\end{pmatrix}$$

giving:

$$D=\frac{1}{2}\|\vec{u}\times\vec{v}\|=\frac12\sqrt{(bc)^2+(ac)^2+(ab)^2}$$

instead of

$$-\frac{bc}{2}+\frac{ac}{2}+\frac{ab}{2}.$$

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading your diagram, but it looks as though you're multiplying the base of your triangle by its hypotenuse, not its height.

Comment: You are a God. I can't believe I forgot to actually compute the norm of the crossproduct... Thank you!!